# Convert dictionaries in cell to subcolumns in multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a pandas DataFrame like the following:

```
                  c  d
a  {'e': 1, 'f': 2}  2
b  {'e': 3, 'f': 4}  5
```

I would now like to expand the dictionaries in the cells to two sub-columns in a multiindex dataframe, like so:

```
     c          d
     e   f
a    1   2      2
b    3   4      5
```

How do I best do this?

Comment: Fix column `'c'` using the duplicate, then use `.set_index()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I explicitly would like a multi-index dataframe. The answer that was referenced as duplicate isn't doing that for me...

Comment: You have asked two questions, however questions should address one issue. The first issue is to fix `'c'` using the duplicate. The second question is how to set a multiindex, which is done with `.set_index()`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, [edit] the question to show what you have done, and specifically what is not working. Always provide a complete [mre] with code, **data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).